# javascript function is not defined on button click

Tags: javascript, function

i am dynamically creating a button element and on its onclick event seting a function call but its always saying removeimg is not defined (removeimg is name of function being called on click of button). hers the code :

link :

http://shri-ram.lifekloud.com/pilot/step4.php
(tab add delete photos)

```
 function removeimg(){        
        //make request to remove the name
        document.getElementById(name).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(btn12).style.display = 'none';
    }



    function showUploadedItem (source) {
        var list = document.getElementById("image-listalbum"),
            li   = document.createElement("li"),
            img  = document.createElement("img");
            var btn = document.createElement('input');
            btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
            btn.setAttribute("value", "Remove");
            btn.setAttribute("class", "t-button");
            var btnId = "btn" + source + "";
            btn.setAttribute("id", btnId);
            var func = "removeimg()";
            btn.setAttribute("onclick", func);


        img.src = 'uploads/'+source;
        li.appendChild(img);
        li.appendChild(btn);
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
```

Comment: why you not use jquery for this simple task.

Comment: Use JQuery, but other than that, I think you need a semicolon inside the string:

    btn.setAttribute("onclick", "removeImg();");

Comment: what is name in removeimg , it should be in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
btn.onclick = removeimg;
```

rather than the string version you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in Javascript have a scope, because they are essentially the same as any other Object. Since your function is defined inside the `$(document).ready();` function it only exists in that scope. You'll have to declare it outside the ready() function to use it on the click of a button.